# Why is Java's Class<T> generic?

Tags: java, generics

Why is Java's `Class<T>` generic?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

So that generic typed methods can be used -

```
Class<Foo> klass = Foo.class;
Foo f = klass.newInstance();
Foo f = klass.cast(Object);
```

Comment: Warning to anyone believing this answer to be correct because it was accepted: This cannot be correct because the code does not compile.  `klass` is uninitialized before it is used.

Comment: ... (follow-up): Notice that code that does compile - namely, `Class<Foo> klass = Foo.class;` - begs the original question, because `Foo.class` seemingly provides the necessary information already.  However, the ability to use generic typed methods is the correct answer; it's just not clear from the given example here.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a reasonably good summary of the advantages:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html

Answer (score 14):

There's a short mention of this in the [Generics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html) section of the 1.5 version of the language guide:

> More surprisingly, class Class has been generified.  Class literals now function as type tokens, providing both run-time and compile-time type information. This enables a style of static factories exemplified by the getAnnotation method in the new AnnotatedElement interface:

```
<T extends Annotation> T getAnnotation(Class<T> annotationType);
```

> This is a generic method. It infers the value of its type parameter T from its argument, and returns an appropriate instance of T, as illustrated by the following snippet:

```
Author a = Othello.class.getAnnotation(Author.class);
```

> Prior to generics, you would have had to cast the result to Author. Also you would have had no way to make the compiler check that the actual parameter represented a subclass of Annotation

Answer (score 8):

The real reason is given by [Neil Gafter](http://gafter.blogspot.nl/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html):

> When we added generics to Java in JDK5, I changed the class
>   java.lang.Class to become a generic type. For example, the type of
>   String.class is now Class < String > . Gilad Bracha coined the term type
>   tokens for this. My intent was to enable a particular style of API,
>   which Joshua Bloch calls the THC, or Typesafe Heterogenous Container
>   pattern.