# Use of Class<...> in Java

Tags: java

I have come across many java programs where I have found a style of programming new to me:

`Class_name<...>`

Can anyone plase explain what is this.?

Comment: It seems that you are asking about [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generics in Java. Take a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 2):

Angular backets are used to specify generics.

Check this post: [Why is Java's Class<T> generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094023/why-is-javas-classt-generic)

Comment: This feature has been added in jdk 5 onwards and purpose is type safety to avoid class cast exception

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/ will help.  generic type is in short saying a param of type Object will in fact be using specified class or interface instead. so you can have an array list with just strings. why - type safety (less bugs that are difficult to spot) and easier to type.